# How can I change the data type stored in Redis using TypeORM?

Tags: caching, redis, typeorm, node-redis

I'm working with TypeORM + Redis to store query results, and I'm having difficulties to change the data type used by TypeORM to store data on Redis (it's string by default).

How can i change to something like JSON types or even Hashs?

I know that TypeORM serialize and deserialize the data automatically, but in my case, query results are getting to big to be stored as strings, so even the RedisInsights program told me to change the data types.

I searched everywhere but i didn't find any solution, maybe it's not implemented yet, but i think that this should be a trivial configuration on TypeORM.